# Symfony 3.4 and Fixtures Bundle

Tags: symfony, fixture

I'm using symfony 3.4.1 with `doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.4.1`

I'm trying to run fixtures, but I have this message when I'm trying to inject the `UserPasswordEncoderInterface` to encode my password.
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#accessing-services-from-the-fixtures

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Too
>   few arguments to function
>   AppBundle\DataFixtures\DataFixtures::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   /srv/api-platform/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Loader.php
>   on line 210 and exactly 1 expected in
>   /srv/api-platform/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/DataFixtures.php:20
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /srv/api-platform/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Loader.php(210):
>
> AppBundle\DataFixtures\DataFixtures->__construct()
>
> ## 1 /srv/api-platform/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Loader.php(390):
>
> Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader->createFixture('AppBundle\DataF...')
>
> ## 2 /srv/api-platform/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Loader.php(82):
>
> Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader->loadFromIterator(Object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
>
> ## 3 /srv/api-platform/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle/Command/LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php(102):
>
> Doctrine\Commo in
>   /srv/api-platform/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/DataFixtures.php on
>   line 20

My Fixtures:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures;

use AppBundle\Entity\TechnicalCenter;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class DataFixtures extends Fixture
{
    /** @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder */
    private $encoder;

    /**
     * DataFixtures constructor.
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder
     */
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    /**
     * Load data fixtures with the passed EntityManager
     *
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $technicalCenter = new TechnicalCenter();
        $technicalCenter->setName('Austerlitz');
        $manager->persist($technicalCenter);

        $admin = new User();
        $admin->setUsername('admin');
        $admin->setPassword($this->encoder->encodePassword($admin, 'admin'));
        $admin->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
        $admin->setTechnicalCenter($technicalCenter);
        $manager->persist($admin);

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

My `security.yml`

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
```

Comment: Are you using the standard services configuration, ie your services.yml file is in the standard place for Symfony 3.4?

Comment: If not (or even if it is) did you try registering your fixture as a service and injecting the encoder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fixtures I inject directly the ContainerInterface by implement it and using the "setContainer" function, for exemple:

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use CoreBundle\Entity\Admin;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LoadAdminData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface {

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $admin = new Admin();
        $admin->setUsername('Test');
        $plainPass = 'admin';
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $encodedPass = $encoder->encodePassword($admin, $plainPass);
        $admin->setPassword($encodedPass);
        $admin->setEmail('test@test.com');

        $manager->persist($admin);
        $manager->flush();
    }
    public function getOrder()
    {
        // the order in which fixtures will be loaded
        // the lower the number, the sooner that this fixture is loaded
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only working solution for Liip and Symfony 3.4 for now.